# Is my SMC damaged?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, power-management

I have a Macbook Pro running 10.9.3 (13D65), Boot ROM Version:  MBP55.00AC.B03
  SMC Version (system): 1.47f2

The fans are always running at full rpm and the kernel task used to take up 90% of the cpu till I found a fix that said to remove a plist entry specific to your Model Identifier. The plist was inside
/System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/
Contents/PlugIns/ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin.kext/.

This helped the kernel task problem, however the fans are still are running at highest the rpm possible. Recently a new problem appeared, now my Mac will randomly go to sleep mode on its own. I have tried resetting the SMC, but this has made no difference. I tried setting the sleep setting to never but it had no effect. I also tried the apps Caffeine and NoSleep, but they've had no effect either. Is this an SMC problem and if so how can I diagnose the damage? Does somebody know where on the logic board the SMC is, just to check it for corrosion or some sort of damage?

Update: http://pastebin.com/iYxwCi0W EtreCheck on Mavericks
Also, I tried to fix the sleep problem by changing the pmset sleep to 0, it worked for a while but its rebooted on its own two times now.

Update: The pmset doesn't really take, however it hasn't restarted on its own anymore. Also the fans are now sometimes running at 230 rpm!

Comment: In my opinion, there is no way to reliably diagnose the issue once you have modified the contents of that kernel extension. I would either revert your changes there, or reinstall OS X and then return back.

Comment: Well I did save the file, so if I were to put it back and reboot. How would I go about diagnosing it then?

Comment: Hard to know without a more comprehensive look. You can run [Etrecheck](http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck) and provide the results with a [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com) if you wish. If you do so, update the original question with the link. Regards.

Comment: What if Yosemite loaded a new SMC to work with the new OS and it's going to be buggy until that OS is released / bugs fixed? You'll probably want to open a support incident with Apple engineering on the developer boards to find out what SMC version you are running or ask here how to determine the proper SMC version for Mavericks.

Comment: Sorry for this, I did see the Community Bulletin and therefore I did try to mention that the problems carried over from Mavericks to Yosemite figured it could be overlooked. As you can see in the EtreCheck info I am only running Yosemite on a portion of my drive, if I were to change the EtreCheck to be based off of my Mavericks could you not put this on hold?

Comment: Be sure to open System Information and edit in the specific boot ROM, SMC and system build version on which you continue to have problems. We can't rule in or out Yosemite without those details - for now let's reopen this. Hopefully you have an SMC version that is appropriate for Mavericks.

Comment: As to your problem, what happens to the fans if you power off and boot to recovery HD. You can probably wait 5 minutes and hear the fan level or open terminal and run top to see what the CPU load is on a stock OS with your hardware and SMC without needing to install a clean OS on an external USB to test if you have problems with your OS.

Comment: Ok, so went into recovery HD the fans were I'm guessing at the same speed, however I couldn't run top, it said command not found. Not sure why it said that...

Comment: @mac_fan_33 because you're not logged in (to the shell, not your account) and can't directly invoke the command within that environment. try: `/usr/bin/top`

Comment: Oh thanks, I'm not too great on terminal. I tried /usr/bin/top and it says no such file or directory. I tried to search for an answer so I wouldn't have to post on here but I'm not sure what to do. I tried echo $PATH and /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin came out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help guys, but I decided to take a look at my logic board and found some places that had been corroded. I removed my logic board and gave it a good clean with isopropyl alcohol and a toothbrush and for now my mac has stopped going to sleep on its own, also fans are back to normal. Hope this works out.